# A variable declared at class level but initialized in page_load loses its scope in a button_click eventhandler?

Tags: asp.net

im new to asp.net.. please bear with me if ma question is way too trivial!!! :)

im using an accordian control within an update panel. and i also have a button to save some data frm the accordian control! - This complete is a user control which is used in another .aspx page.

now in the page_load event of the user control i initialize my database connection which works absolutely fine while loading data to the accordian.. but when i click on save, in the save button click even handler the database connection object is always null..!! (even though it is initialized in the page_load) please help..

.ascx is as here:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="PrefPanel" runat="server"  >
  <ContentTemplate>
    <ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="PrefAccordion" runat="server" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" 
        HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected"  ContentCssClass="accordionContent" 
        BackColor="#E8EAF7" Height="530px" Width="500px" AutoSize="None" RequireOpenedPane="false"
        BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="Black">
        <Panes>

            <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="ProjCategoryPaneID" runat="server">
                <Header > Project Category</Header>
                <Content> 
                    <asp:Panel ID="ProjCategoryPanel" runat="server" Width="100%">
                        <table align="center" width="100%">
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:CheckBoxList RepeatDirection="Vertical" TextAlign="Left" ID="ProjCategoryItem1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CausesValidation="false" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </Content>
            </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
<asp:Button ID="btnSavePref" CssClass="buttonsmall" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="60px" OnClick="btnSavePref_Click"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancelPref" CssClass="buttonsmall" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Width="60px" />
</ContentTemplate>  
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

the code behind is as here:

```
public partial class UserPreferences : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        private EAReportingDAL m_DataAccessLayer = null;

        // Projects Category
        Panel projectCategoryPanel;
        CheckBoxList projectCategoryList;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings            ["BSCDB"].ConnectionString;
            m_DataAccessLayer = new EAReportingDAL(connectionString);
                            LoadUserPreferences();
         }

        protected void btnSavePref_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string userName = this.Page.User.Identity.Name;
            DataSet availabeData = m_DataAccessLayer.GetUserPreferences(this.Page.User.Identity.Name, Constants.ProjectsUIView);
        }
}
```

in the button click event handler btnSavePref_Click() the the db connection object m_DataAccessLayer is always null, but whereas the same object in LoadUserPreferences() [which i haven't pasted here though] works fine! plz guide me where im wrong or if someone needs more details!!

Comment: Without relevant code we're blind. Please enlighten us.

Comment: Viniez - I meant "please post relevant code". I see you posted, so I'll try giving an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with UpdatePanel mechanics but maybe you defined it in such a way that it bypass the `Page_Load` method.

What I suggest is moving the code create the data access layer to separate method then calling this method from both the page load and button click handler:

```
private void InitDataAccess()
{
    //ignore if already created
    if (m_DataAccessLayer != null)
        return;
    String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings            ["BSCDB"].ConnectionString;
    m_DataAccessLayer = new EAReportingDAL(connectionString);
    LoadUserPreferences();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitDataAccess();
}

protected void btnSavePref_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitDataAccess();
    string userName = this.Page.User.Identity.Name;
    DataSet availabeData = m_DataAccessLayer.GetUserPreferences(this.Page.User.Identity.Name, Constants.ProjectsUIView);
}
```